# To Only You or Only To You?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, word-order

I need some native English speakers to answer this one.

Is it

1. "Alarms are visible to only you."

OR

2. "Alarms are visible only to you."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say they were both fine.

Comment: I would consider the first unidiomatic, though not 'incorrect'. _Visible to you only_ would be more formal, _only to you_ more natural and colloquial.

Comment: They both seem fine to me. It's a free choice between two slightly different (and perfectly grammatical) ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Assuming the electronic devices:  The fourth alternative, 'Alarms are only visible to you' is colloquial/idiomatic (though pedants would chip in with 'only visible and never audible?'

Answer (score 1):

"Alarms are visible to only you" sounds very awkward, if not flat out wrong. I don't think a native speaker would phrase it like that.

"Alarms are visible only to you" is perfectly fine, but consider also...

"Alarms are visible to you only" rather old fashioned and formal. Perhaps comes to mind because of the James Bond book/film *For Your Eyes Only* (if you dig up the theme song to this on YouTube, you'll hear a few you/only constructions, and see some nice things too!). A more natural variant might be "Alarms are visible to you alone."

What I think *I'd* say would be none of the above, but "alarms are only visible to you."